# Upper triangular matrix group

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

I am currently in an abstract algebra class and my teacher told us to look at the upper triangular matrix, $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1 \end{array} \right)$ for $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$, p being a prime number.

Specifically she posed the questions, prove it is a group, find the order, find the order of the center, and to give a simple description for the isomorphism type of $G/Z(G)$.

I was able to prove that is a group using the normal axioms and was able to prove the order by simply recognizing there are $p$ possibilities for each variable a,b,c so the order was $p^3$.

I am having trouble in establishing which matrices are commutative and would appreciate some guidance in my troubling times.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not calculate $[A,B]=AB-BA$ for two of your general matrices $A, B$ and see if this vanishes?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you compare $MM'$ and $M'M$, you'll see the only place for a lack of commutativity is the upper right corner, as we should  have $ac'=a'c$. Now if you suppose  $M$ is in the centre, you should have this equality for *all* $a',c'$. What does this imply for $a$ and $c$?

Comment: So this implies that a and c are not relatively prime?

Comment: Relatively prime is meaningless in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. Choose $a'=1, c'=0$, then the converse.

Comment: So a and c must equal 0 for the matrix to be in the center?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So the order would simply be p in that case.